# Selector returning no results in IE 11

Tags: snap.svg

I'm attempting to get all group elements within a fragment that have an attribute with a specific value.

All but IE (11 in my case) return me the results I expect. Any ideas on how I can adjust this to get the result I expect in IE?

`fragment.selectAll('g[v\\:groupContext=\'group\']');`

Here's jsFiddle example of the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/30oh3n04/1/

Console should log `1` but in IE 11 it logs `0`.

Comment: Hmm not even sure its creating a fragment correct ?

Comment: Could be that my jsfiddle example isn't a very good one. The fragment I have in my live code comes from a `Snap.load`.

Comment: I think parse should still deal with a fragment ok, so I was just wodnering if it wasn't an issue with the selector, but possibly an issue with the fragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try lowercase for selector string.

```
fragment.selectAll('g[v\\:groupcontext=\'group\']');
```

I think this SVG code was parsed by rule of HTML so "groupContext" was treated as "groupcontext".
Snap.svg uses innerHTML property to parse SVG source.